# How to get environment parameters in pipeline compitable jenkins SimpleBuildStep plugin?

Tags: java, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I just added pipeline compitability but I can't get any of env parameters. 
My class have a definition as below:

`public class JobBuildStep extends Builder implements SimpleBuildStep`

and perform method:

`public void perform(@Nonnull Run<?, ?> run, @Nonnull FilePath workspace, @Nonnull Launcher launcher, @Nonnull TaskListener listener) throws AbortException`

Could anyone please tell me what are the options to fix it?
I also found an issue with it - https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-29144
The last comment says I should implement `Step` instead, is it `org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.steps.Step` from

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.jenkins-ci.plugins.workflow</groupId>
  <artifactId>workflow-basic-steps</artifactId>
  <version>2.7</version>
</dependency>
```

package? If so how can I use 
`@Override public StepExecution start(StepContext stepContext) throws Exception`
method?

Comment: I previously used `extends Builder implements SimpleBuildStep` for freestyle jobs and pipelines. I changed the implementation to your example, but the plugin is not found as freestyle build step anymore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was done by Step extending:

`public class ExampleBuildStep extends Step`

and creating perform method with EnvVars as input:

`public void perform(@Nonnull Run<?, ?> run, @Nonnull FilePath workspace, @Nonnull Launcher launcher, @Nonnull TaskListener listener, @Nonnull EnvVars environment) throws AbortException`

and here are the implemented methods by Step class:

```
@Override
public StepExecution start(StepContext stepContext) {

  return new Execution(stepContext, this);
}

private final static class Execution extends SynchronousNonBlockingStepExecution<Void> {

  private transient final ExampleBuildStep step;

  protected Execution(
    @Nonnull StepContext context,
    ExampleBuildStep step) {
    super(context);
    this.step = step;
  }

  @Override
  protected Void run() throws Exception {

    FilePath workspace = getContext().get(FilePath.class);
    workspace.mkdirs();
    step.perform(
      getContext().get(Run.class),
      workspace,
      getContext().get(Launcher.class),
      getContext().get(TaskListener.class),
      getContext().get(EnvVars.class));
    return null;
  }
}
```

And then you will be able to use it by the name that returns by getFunctionName() in your StepDescriptor:

```
@Extension
public static class DescriptorImpl extends StepDescriptor {

  @Override
  public Set<? extends Class<?>> getRequiredContext() {
    return ImmutableSet.of(FilePath.class, Run.class, Launcher.class, TaskListener.class, EnvVars.class);
  }

  @Override
  public String getFunctionName() {
    return "run_your_step";
  }

  public boolean isApplicable(Class<? extends AbstractProject> aClass) {
    // Indicates that this builder can be used with all kinds of project types
    return true;
  }

  public String getDisplayName() {
    return "Example of step plugin";
  }
}
```

Comment: Does `Step`also work as a build step for both pipelines and freestylejobs, similar to `SimpleBuildStep`?

Comment: @MatthiasSommer, sorry for long response, I kinda dropped developing such stuff, but as far as I remember it should be available to freestylejobs as well. please correct me if I am wrong. See the isApplicable function I guess.