# Setting env var and using from pipeline plugin

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-pipeline

I have the following in my Jenkins file:

```groovy
pipeline {
    agent any
    environment {
        SOME_VAR = "placeholder"
    }

    stages {
        stage('Initialize'){
            // My plugin
            myPlugin 
        }
    }
}
```

The `myPlugin` is a `SimpleBuildStep` (implementing `Builder`) plugin, that needs to access the *SOME_VAR* variable:

```groovy
   EnvVars environment = build.getEnvironment(listener);

    for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : environment.entrySet()) {
        listener.getLogger().format("\t%s\t: %s%n", entry.getKey(), entry.getValue());
    }
```

The problem is, I don't see the *SOME_VAR* in the list of variables available to the plugin. Is there a different way to set environment variables that are available to pipeline plugins?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get environment parameters in pipeline compitable jenkins SimpleBuildStep plugin?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50442303/how-to-get-environment-parameters-in-pipeline-compitable-jenkins-simplebuildstep)

Comment: You can find a solution for this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50442303/how-to-get-environment-parameters-in-pipeline-compitable-jenkins-simplebuildstep). This is how got it working. Instead of using `SimpleBuildstep`, you have to extend the `Step`class.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the jenkins environment tools path, like this.

```
pipeline{

    agent any 

    environment{
           PATH = "${tool 'NodeJS'}/bin:${env.PATH}"
           PATH = "${tool 'latestANT'}/bin:${env.PATH}"
    }

    stages {
        stage('Initialize'){
            // My plugin
            myPlugin 
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: That's the thing - inside `myPlugin` I don't get any updated or added values when I get environment using `build.getEnvironment(listener)`.

Comment: There is an [open ticket](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-29144). "SimpleBuildStep.perform needs to be given an EnvVars argument. Otherwise there is no way for an implementation to observe any local environment variable settings." One recommends to implement `Step` instead.